# MongoDB Query With Like

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to query a collection with a like query, which we do in relational DB. I am trying to get a config which ends with **LOYALTY_SERVICE_ENABLED**

However, I couldn't use like query as I wanted. Can you explain the difference between the two queries below? Thanks

**RETURNS 1 RESULT**

```
db.getCollection("configurations").find(
    { key: 'co:food:LOYALTY_SERVICE_ENABLED' }
);
```

**RETURNS 0 RESULT**

```
db.getCollection("configurations").find(
    { key: '/.*LOYALTY_SERVICE_ENABLED' }
);
```

Equal SQL Query:`Select * from configurations where key like '%LOYALTY_SERVICE_ENABLED';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a typo. can you try it like this?

```
db.getCollection(“configurations”).find({"key" : /.*LOYALTY_SERVICE_ENABLED.*/}).pretty();
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the `$regex` evaluation query operator to use a pattern matching string, I have modified your code to reflect that.

```
db.getCollection("configurations").find(
    { key: {$regex: /.*LOYALTY_SERVICE_ENABLED/} }
);
```

> Notice you don't need the quotes `' '` around the pattern string.

More details can be found [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/)

Comment: thanks for reply. Main problem was using ' ' inside of query. When I omit that as above answer, it fixed. Thanks